# How to turn on manual focus for Sony α7R II?

Tags: camera-settings, manual-focus, sony-alpha

There is an `AF/MF | AEL` switch on my Sony α7R II. If I switch this to `AF/MF`, and then press the button inside the switch, nothing happens on the viewfinder screen or back panel screen.

How do I turn on manual focus for a Sony α7R II?

Answer (score 3):

[From the online manual](http://docs.esupport.sony.com/dvimag/ILCE-7_ILCE-7R_guide/en/contents/TP0000226559.html):

You can easily switch the focusing mode from auto to manual and vice versa while shooting without changing your holding position.

Switch the AF/MF/AEL switch lever to the AF/MF position, then press the AF/MF button.

**During auto focus:** 
Temporarily switches the focusing mode to manual. Adjust the focus while the AF/MF button is being held down.

**During manual focus:** 
Temporarily switches the focusing mode to auto while the AF/MF button is held down, and locks the focus.

**Hint:**
If you select [AF/MF Ctrl Toggle] in [AF/MF Button] under [Custom Key Settings], the focusing mode remains switched even if you remove your finger from the button.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the button you mentioned only works while you are **holding it down**. You literally have to keep holding it down while you focus and until you press the shutter release. To me, that is a total pain in the rear. From the way you worded your question, it seems you want to switch to manual focus  "permanently" (you know, until you switch back to auto-focus).

There are two-ish things you can do to switch to manual focus:

You can use the menus: { Camera Settings (camera icon) ; Page 3 ; Focus Mode }. You can also set up the function menu to include that setting so you can get to it faster.

You can set that same button that you mentioned to **toggle** between manual focus and auto focus, rather than be in only "push to manually focus and don't dare let up that frikkin' button" mode: { Menu ; Custom Settings (gear icon) ; Page 7 ; Custom Key Settings ; Page 2 ; AF/MF Button = AF/MF Ctrl Toggle }. Yeah, this is the one I use. (You could also set any of the other customizable buttons to do the same thing. But I just use this button for now, mostly because it already has the label by it.